# Laravel class App\Models\Lead does not exist when it clearly does

Tags: php, laravel-5, namespaces

I have a `Lead` model under `App\Models\Lead`.

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lead extends Model
{

...

}
```

I am referencing this model in my `LeadService` class which is in `App\Services\LeadService`:

```
namespace App\Services;
use App\Models\Lead;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class LeadService
{

public function __construct(Lead $lead)
    {
        $this->model = $lead;
        $this->pagination = 25;
    }

}
```

I keep getting the error:

> Class App\Models\Lead does not exist

I've cleared all my cache and have also tried `composer dump autoload` but keep getting the same issue.

I'm using Laravel 5.5 on PHP 7.1

Anyone know what's going on here?

**Update:**

Error log:

> [2018-06-10 03:27:59] production.ERROR: Class App\Models\Lead does not
>   exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: 0): Class
>   App\Models\Lead does not exist at
>   /srv/users/asianwed/apps/aws-booking-system/public/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:811,
>   ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected '}' at
>   /srv/users/asianwed/apps/aws-booking-system/public/app/Models/Lead.php:58)

Comment: View laravel logs may get more error details...

Comment: Seem you're try to use repository pattern right ?

Comment: @TruongDang I've updated my question with the error log. I guess you could call it the repository pattern but all I'm doing is using a Service class.

Comment: Look at this error, you have an syntax error  in your `Lead` model : `syntax error, unexpected '}' at /srv/users/asianwed/apps/aws-booking-system/public/app/Models/Lead.php:58)`

Comment: Damn. Missing semi colon. Always gets me. Thanks!!

Comment: Allways make sure check your laravel logs. This really helpfull

Comment: Yeah it was because the error was showing `Class App\Models\Lead does not exist` so I assumed it was a namespace issue.